Freitag and Busam Complex analysis conformal map condition theorem
Theorem I.5.15 of the book (Freitag&Busam complex analysis) says: A map $f:D\to D'$, where $D,D'$ open in $\mathbb{C}$, is locally conformal if and only if it is analytic and its derivative is analytic and does not vanish anywhere.
At this point in the book, Cauchy integral theorem or CIF haven't at all been mentioned yet. So where do they get "its derivative is analytic" from? It seems to me the definitions and remarks immediately preceding this statement in the book can only lead to continuity of the derivative, not analyticity. What did I miss? Thanks in advance.

Analyticity plus constant nonzero leading first power means, up to first order, the map is complex linear, ie. a combination of a translation by $z_0$, a rotation by $\phi$ with center $z_0$, a positive radial dilation by $r$ and a final translation by $w_0$ .
$$w= w_0 + r e^{i \phi} \  (z-z_0) + \sum_{k=2}^\infty a_k (z-z_0)^k $$
with
$r > 0$
The map conserves angles at $x_0$.
By translation invariance, for translations along the greatest circle without zeros of $f'$,  the map is conformal, i.e. real isogonal 1-1.
For $r=0$, the map multiplies angles at $z_0$ by $r e^{i \phi} \mapsto r^n \ e^{i n \phi}$ producing an $n$-fold cover of the unit circle with $n$ the first non-zero exponent in the power series.

Sorry, I only saw this answer now. But I don't understand what you are saying, or how it relates to what I asked.
